# Regex negation in vim

Tags: regex, vim, regex-lookarounds

In vim I would like to use regex to highlight each line that ends with a letter, that is preceeded by neither `//` nor `:`. I tried the following

```
syn match systemverilogNoSemi "\(.*\(//\|:\).*\)\@!\&.*[a-zA-Z0-9_]$" oneline
```

This worked very good on comments, but did not work on lines containing colon.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because with this regex vim can choose any point for starting match for your regular expression. Obviously it chooses the point where first concat matches (i.e. does not have `//` or `:`). These things are normally done by using either

```
\v^%(%(\/\/|\:)@!.)*\w$
```

(removed first concat and the branch itself, changed `.*` to `%(%(\/\/|\:)@!.)*`; replaced collection with equivalent `\w`; **added anchor pointing to the start of line**): if you need to match the whole line. Or negative look-behind if you need to match only the last character. You can also just add anchor to the first concat of your variant (you should remove trailing `.*` from the first concat as it is useless, and the branch symbol for the same reason).

Note: I have no idea why your regex worked for comments. It does not work with comments the way you need it in all cases I checked.

Comment: Hi,either I'm doing it wrong or I'm missing something. When I search using the regex you gave it works, but when I try to import it to my vim plugin it does not match. Can you please show the format for: `syn match...` Thanks

Comment: It works for me in `syn match` as-is: `syn match Error '\v^%(%(\/\/|\:)@!.)*\w$'`.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you?

```
^\(\(//\|:\)\@<!.\)*[a-zA-Z0-9_]$
```